# How and why does an integer get typecast into String when using "+"?

Tags: java, casting

While I'm executing this code, writing `+` is converting my integer into a String.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String...string){

    int m=9;
    int k=10;
    String s=new String(m +"");//automatic type conversion from int to string
    String j=m+"" +k;////automatic type conversion from int to string
    System.out.println(s+j);
    String s1=String.valueOf(m);
    System.out.println(s1);
}

}
```

I'm unable to understand what `+` is doing here, and how it's getting converted into a String. Does this have something to do with the right to left precedence of the `=` operator?

Comment: it is operator overloading concept......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this have Got something to do with precedence  with right to left of `=` operator ?

Answer: *No*

And it's has *got nothing to do With Integer Type too*.
Why ? because
Here is what [JSL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4) say

> String conversion applies only to an operand of the binary + operator
>   which is not a String when the other operand is a String.
>
> In this single special case, the non-String operand to the + is
>   converted to a String (§5.1.11) and evaluation of the + operator
>   proceeds as specified in §15.18.1.

So even if you write any other type variable it will convert it Consider this snippet

```
public static void main(String...string){
    double u=9.0;
    System.out.println(u+"hi");


}
```

It gives me output

```
9.0hi
```

Now Coming to How ?

For the code snippet that i posted 
Here is the part of compiled code of this

```
public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_VARARGS
    Code:
      stack=5, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: ldc2_w        #16                 // double 9.0d
         3: dstore_1
         4: getstatic     #18                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljav
a/io/PrintStream;
         7: new           #24                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
        10: dup
        11: dload_1
        12: invokestatic  #26                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf
:(D)Ljava/lang/String;
        15: invokespecial #32                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.
"<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        18: ldc           #35                 // String hi
        20: invokevirtual #37                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.
append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        23: invokevirtual #41                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.
toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        26: invokevirtual #45                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.prin
tln:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

So internally it invokes `valueOf()` method to convert double or non-string operand to String and than invokes `append()` to convert it into String totally .
Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to make the answer more simpler hence I am posting this.

`'+' is the only operator in java that is overloaded for String type for string concatenation`.

So if any one of the two operands is String.. the whole operation is overloaded for concatenation.

So `string+(any other datatype) =  string.`

So for any other operands use parentthesis along with string

So `5+5+"" =55`

and `(5+5)+"" = 10`

**NOTE: It has nothing to do with right to left precedence**